# Different location directives in ngnix

Tags: php, nginx

I am new in ngnix and I don't understand very well the location directive. I have a website with the folloging configuration:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
}

#assets

location /web/assets/ {
    rewrite ^(/web/assets/.*)$ $1 break;
}

location /web/assets/cache/ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/web/assets/cache/(.*)$ /web/assets/cache/index.php last;
    }
}
```

In the website, all requests are redirected to index.php, but there is an "assets" folder that I don't want to redirect (/web/assets/). Inside this folder there is a subfolder called "cache". If any file inside this subfolder is requested and the file doesn't exist, the request is redirected to a php file that create the file and save it in cache. This is useful for example for preprocessed css, js, etc, the files are created the first time they are required.

This configuration works well, but I'd like to send some headers to assets files, according to html5 boilderplate suggestions, for example expires rules for static content (https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/conf/expires.conf), and when I add these directives:

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

The previous redirection doesn't work. I guest it's because nginx doesn't execute all matches locations but only the first one. My question is how to combine rewrite and header directives in ngnix config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request can only be handled by one location block. Also, the usage of `if` is not a good practice. [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) can be much more efficient. Also, you have a rewrite rule that rewrites to the same uri (totally useless).

Allow me to rewrite your conf to what I believe is more efficient for your needs and please lt me know if I got something wrong

```
#this is just fine as it was
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
}

#web assets should be served directly
location /web/assets/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @mycache;
}

#this is the mycache location, called when assets are not found
location @mycache {
  expires 1y;
  access_log on;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
  rewrite ^/web/assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/cache/index.php last;
}

#some specific files in the web/assets directory. if this matches, it is preferred over the location web/assets because it is more specific
location ~* /web/assets/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
  try_files $uri $uri/ @mycache;
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* /web/assets/.*\.(css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
  try_files $uri $uri/ @mycache;
}
```

I may have typos or errors, I don't have means to test right now. Let me know

Comment: Thank you, @foibs, I've changed the config file adding your code and seems all work fine. I'm going to make more test and I let you know.

Comment: Hello again. There are some problems with your code. (It's tested here: https://wok.io/).

Comment: Sorry, I've pressed "enter" in the previous comment. I want the redirection is made only if the file does not exist in /web/assets/cache, not for all files in /web/assets. Now, the files not redirected (loaded out of /cache, for example images) are not loaded. I can see also that the expire header is not send

Comment: I've edited my conf. I see many 404s in the page. Is the correct directory `web/assets` or `wok/assets`? Also, some access and error logs would be helpful

Comment: Ah, ok, the correct directory is wok, not web. I'm going to make the changes.

Comment: Thank you. For a second assets folder (for example, /other-folder/assets), I have to duplicate the code and create other named redirect (for example @mycache2), Am i right?

Comment: Yes, or you could use the power of regex to accept two or more directories like `location ~* /(web|wok)/assets/`  and `rewrite ^/(web|wok)/assets/(.*)$ /$1/assets/cache/index.php last;` and `location ~* /(web|wok)/assets/ {`

Comment: Sorry again. There is a problem with the cached images. For example, the url https://wok.io/assets/cache/avatars/resizeCrop,30,30-ed0c54799e64d261fd340ead59590fae.png should be redirected to index.php and execute the php to generate this image (get the original image, execute the resizeCrop method to 30x30 px and save it in the cache/avatars folder). But instead execute the php, it returns the php code of index.php as an image. Maybe I have to configurate ngnix to execute this file as php?

Comment: Nginx cannot run the php code. You must set up fastcgi or some other webserver like apache with mod_php and proxy the request so that it can be processed. In any case you must create a `location ~* \.php$` block and set up the fastcgi or proxy_pass in there.

Comment: Yes, I have this code
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

Comment: For some reason, your location block for the fcgi is not used. Probably you have to move it higher in your conf file. Check for more here -> http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: Ok, fixed! I've moved this block to top and now it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help!!